# valueerror: can't reshape array of size 315 into shape (32,32)

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I'm trying to use the code in this page: https://medium.com/@muskulpesent/create-numpy-array-of-images-fecb4e514c4b

```
import cv2
import glob
import numpy as np

#Train data
train = []
train_labels = []
files = glob.glob (r"C:\Users\Downloads\All_Codes\image\0\*.png") # your image path
for myFile in files:
    image = cv2.imread (myFile ,cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    input_img_resize=cv2.resize(image,(64,64))
    train.append (input_img_resize)
    train_labels.append([0])

print(train) 
print(len(train))

files = glob.glob (r"C:\Users\Downloads\All_Codes\image\1\*.png")
for myFile in files:
    image = cv2.imread (myFile,cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    print(image)
    #input_img_resize=cv2.resize(image,(64,64))
    train.append (image)
    train_labels.append([1])


print(len(train_labels))
print(train_labels)

train = np.array(train,dtype=object) #as mnist
train_labels = np.array(train_labels,dtype=object) #as mnist
# convert (number of images x height x width x number of channels) to (number of images x (height * width *3)) 
# for example (120 * 40 * 40 * 3)-> (120 * 4800)
train = np.reshape(train,(train.shape[0],64,64))


# save numpy array as .npy formats
np.save('train',train)
np.save('train_labels',train_labels)
```

But I had some errors. The problem is that I get the same error every time I attempt to read my images and reshaping them using np.reshape. I searched a lot and used so many codes. They are all the same. That I can't shape **(the number of images in my dataset)** to **(32, 32)** which is the shape I want to insert to my CNN model. The only thing I know for sure is the images in my dataset are of different shapes. Is this why I'm having a diffculty in reshaping them? then what's the point of using "resize" and "reshape"?

the first error is:

```
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 315 into shape (315,32,32)
```

for this line:

```
train = np.reshape(train,[train.shape[0],32,32])
```

Comment: If `train` has shape (315,) and object dtype, it means that it is a 1d array of images.  `reshape` cannot change the number of elements in the array.  Nor can it merge those 315 images into one 3d array.  `np.stack(train)` can do that - provided all the images have the same shape (and same number of color channels).

Comment: In the original code the dtype='float32'. But this line causes another error. [ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.]That's why I changed it to object. Does this have anything related to why my array is 1d?

Comment: [array([[ 78,  36,  75, ...,   0,  11,   0],
       [165,  86, 195, ..., 108,  53, 186],
       [ 93, 103,  97, ...,  45,  69, 126],
       ...,
       [115, 106,  86, ..., 175, 167, 146],
       [143, 192, 155, ..., 117, 124,  87],
       [170, 106, 141, ..., 103, 152, 201]], dtype=uint8) This is the shape of my image before the np.reshape

Comment: This is after the cv2.resize: [[ 77  90 144 ...   0   0   0]
 [  0 240   2 ... 240   2   0]
 [164  14   0 ...   0   0   0]
 ...
 [  0   0   0 ...   0   0   0]
 [144 144 144 ...   0   0   0]
 [  0   0   0 ...   0   0   0]]

Comment: You show a summary of the values, you haven't shown the `shape` (a tuple like `(32,32,3)` or `(64,64)`,

Comment: It was (315,) (315, 1) for x and y respectively.

Answer (score 0):

So, I solved the problem.

```
import cv2
import glob
import numpy as np
import PIL.Image

#Train data
train = []
train_labels = []
files = glob.glob (r"\train\0\*.png") # your image path
for myFile in files:
    image = cv2.imread (myFile ,cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    input_img_resize=cv2.resize(image,(64,64))
    train.append (input_img_resize)
    train_labels.append([0])

#print(train) 
#print(len(train))

files = glob.glob (r"\train\1\*.png")
for myFile in files:
    image = cv2.imread (myFile,cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    input_img_resize=cv2.resize(image,(64,64))
    #print(input_img_resize)
    train.append (input_img_resize)
    train_labels.append([1])


print(len(train))
print(len(train_labels))

train = np.array(train,dtype="float32") #as mnist
train_labels = np.array(train_labels,dtype="float32") #as mnist
train = np.reshape(train,(-1,64,64,1))
```

I resized my images using cv2.resize (inside the loop)
Then did a reshape using np.reshape.

If I relied on one of them, it dose not work. I have to add them both. 
The output is:

315                  #len for x and y

315

(315, 64, 64)         #after cv2.resize

(315, 1)

(315, 64, 64, 1)      #after np.reshape

(315, 1)